# scipy optimizer - restrict number of securities with wgt > 0

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimize

I have a equity portfolio optimization (scipy optimizer > minimize) and want to set a constraint that restricts the number of stocks (nosec = 50) in the portfolio. I tried the following constraint:

```
constr_nosec = {'type': 'eq',
    'fun': lambda weights: (nosec - sum(1 for x in weights if x > 0.0000001))}
```

Unfortunately, the optimization does not bring the expected result with a portfolio of 50 stocks.

Comment: You cannot do this *exactly* without discrete-optimization methods, which are not available in scipy: keywords branch-and-bound, integer-programming. On the *heuristic* side there are *proxy-models* like l1-norm penalties. The problem itself often is called cardinality-constrained optimization (and is NP-hard) or maybe *feature-selection* in ML. Furthermore, most of scipy's solvers expect twice-differentiability in objective and constraints which cannot work with *ifs*. See related [academic intro](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/l1_slides.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. But is there any solver in Python which is able to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: We don't know your problem. There probably is, but it's totally unclear if you are doing convex discrete optimization (probably) or general nonlinear discrete optimization.

Comment: This is often modeled as a MIQP (Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming) problem. MIQP solvers are readily available.

Comment: The overall problem is the following:
1) the main objective is to maximize the expected returns (while ignoring risk)
2) constraint 1: max 50 securities with wgt > 0 (out of 500 in the benchmark)
3) security constraint: set lower and upper wgt bounds for each security individually (+/- 50bps vs benchmark weight)
4) group constraint: max sector weight relative to benchmark = 5%
5) group constraint: max region weight relative to benchmark = 5%
So, is MIQP the appropriate solver to tackle this problem?

Comment: No risk, so this is reduced to a linear MIP problem.